# Angular 4 typescript Decorators are not valid here

Tags: angular, typescript

The following code

```
let isBrowserFactory2=function(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string){ return isPlatformBrowser(platformId);}
```

Gets the following error:

```
Decorators are not valid here
```

And this one

```
let isBrowserFactory=(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string):boolean=> isPlatformBrowser(platformId)
```

Gets the `Expression expected` error.

- Why I can't use typescript's parameter decorators for a function?
- How can I use `@Inject()` to inject something into a factory method?

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Inject` in the constructor.

```
isBrowserFactory: boolean;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId string) { 
  this.isBrowserFactory = this.isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}
```

This way you are declaring `platformId` injecting `PLATFORM_ID`. And then, you can call your method `isPlatformBrowser` that I belive returns a boolean.

Comment: Basically correct, but `class` methods are supported, not just constructors. Object literal concise methods are _not_ supported thouigh

Comment: @AluanHaddad I thought you had to use decorators before class declaration or inside the `constructor`.

Comment: Decorators are valid on class members, class member parameters, and classes themselves.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh! Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad to help. I updated my comment slightly for clarity. If you edit your answer, I would like to vote for it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks! You helped indeed. I think that this way could be clearer (updated answer). I understood what the OP was trying to do and I believe this way he may achieve it. Thanks for your help! :D